# Beautiful Soup: Select a row in a table if a cell is containing a word

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

Thank you if you are paying attention to my post,

After many researches, I could not find the mean to only scrape the row of a table if a cell is containing a particular value.

More specifically: I want to keep the row that contains the word "oui" in the last column of the following table:

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="tdhg" align="left"><b>Liste des candidats</b></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>Voix</strong></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>%&nbsp;Inscrits</strong></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>%&nbsp;Exprimés</strong></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>Elu(e)</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdcbf" align="left">M.&nbsp;Jean-François LAMOUR&nbsp;(UMP) </td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">23&nbsp;964</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  33,01</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  54,60</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="center">oui
                          &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdcbf" align="left">M.&nbsp;Gilles ALAYRAC&nbsp;(RDG) </td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">19&nbsp;927</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  27,45</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  45,40</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="center">
                          &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I first tried going through a regex, I successfully find the matching word but it seems complicated to keep the row concerned so I decided to change the method and go through BeautifulSoup.

The best I made so far is:

```
url='www.someurl.com'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
response = requests.get(url.format())
html_soup = soup(response.content, 'lxml')
html_soup.select('td.tdcd')
```

I cannot manage to go further, in particular stating to keep the 'tr' where the 'tdcd' is containing 'oui'. Even if I read the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/, it is quite hard to consider the value of a cell as a child if I am not mistaking.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find `td.tdcd` that containing `oui` that select it parent

```
html_soup = soup(response.content, 'lxml')
tds = html_soup.select('td.tdcd')

for td in tds :
  if 'oui' in td.text:
    print(td.parent)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it definitely seems to be the thing I was looking for! I focused on Children, not on Parents, it is quite an interesting approach. Just a last little question: why td.parent alone displays the row without 'oui' inside (this is just to fully understand the mechanics) ?

Comment: it display `oui` you can test it on https://repl.it/@uingtea/PythonTester

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after. Just read into a dataframe, then filter the dataframe

```
html = '''<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="tdhg" align="left"><b>Liste des candidats</b></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>Voix</strong></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>%&nbsp;Inscrits</strong></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>%&nbsp;Exprimés</strong></td>
<td class="tdhv"><strong>Elu(e)</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdcbf" align="left">M.&nbsp;Jean-François LAMOUR&nbsp;(UMP) </td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">23&nbsp;964</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  33,01</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  54,60</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="center">oui
                          &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdcbf" align="left">M.&nbsp;Gilles ALAYRAC&nbsp;(RDG) </td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">19&nbsp;927</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  27,45</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="right">  45,40</td>
<td class="tdcd" align="center">
                          &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>'''

import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html(html)[0]

# Keep any rows that have 'oui' in the row; doesn't matter which column
filter_table = table[table.values == 'oui']

# Or if you specifically need to look in the last column
#filter_table = table[table.iloc[:,-1] == 'oui']

# Or specific column name
#filter_table = table[table[4] == 'oui']
```

**Output:**

```
print (filter_table)
                               0       1     2     3    4
1  M. Jean-François LAMOUR (UMP)  23 964  3301  5460  oui
```

**Alternative:**

Here you can iterate through the rows, and only append if it contains `'oui'`

```
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data_rows = html_soup.select('tr')

rows = []
for row in data_rows:
    data = [ x.text.strip() for x in row.find_all('td',{'class':'tdcd'})]
    if 'oui' in data:
        rows.append(data)
        
table = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer which seems quite consistent. Well I did not think about filtering at the panda's stage but it could do the trick. The issue is I am scrapping a bunch of variable on the same pages so they will repeat at each pages for each rows (even if it does not contain 'oui') and because I have a lot of pages I wanted to filter before storing into a panda file.

Comment: ahh ok. I'l work on an alternate solution too. But ya that makes sense

Comment: Thank you very much !